# What type of discontinuity is $\sin(1/x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

For those of you familiar with the graph of $\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$, things get quite 'intense'[image] as $x \to 0$.

Is this a removable discontinuity or an infinite discontinuity or even discontinuous at all?
Lastly, is it differentiable at $x = 0$?

Comment: It's not even defined at $x=0.$ How would you expect it to be differentiable there?

Comment: You can't remove this discontinuity.  No matter what value of $f(0)$ you choose, there will be $x$ values arbitrarily close to $0$ which have $f$ values bigger than say $\frac{1}{2}$.  If $f(x) = x \sin (\frac{1}{x})$ on the other hand....

Comment: Sugata, although in the realm of this question, you are absolutely right, in general your remark does needs some reservation. Example: f(x)=x²sin(1/x) is not defined at x=0 either, so it is discontinuous. However, the limit x→0 exists (by Squeeze theorem)and with the limit definition of the derivative, it can be easily shown f '(0)=0 although the derivative is not continuous at 0. This was my professors favorite example in our Calc class to show that if the discontinuity is removable, the derivative may exist through its limit definition. Don't try to verify it with the TI of course :)

Answer (score 7):

First, the function $$f(x) = \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ isn't defined at $0$. So it is not continuous. For a function to be differentiable it needs to be continuous, so it also isn't differentiable.

Now besides not being defined at $0$, the limit:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)
$$
also doesn't exist. So it isn't a removable discontinuity. One might call this an [essential discontinuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Examples). As defined in the Wikipedia article, one might also call this an infinite discontinuity (but in my opinion one should keep that term for then one of the sided limits is plus or minus infinity).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what "infinite discontinuity" is, but $\,x=0\,$ is a discontinuity point of the second, and strongest, kind: the one sided limits of the function there don't even exist in the generalized form:

$$x_n:=\frac{1}{2n\pi}\;,\;n\in\Bbb N\Longrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\frac{1}{x_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin 2n\pi =0$$

and now repeat the above with

$$x_n:=\frac{2}{(4n-1)\pi}\;,\;\;x_n:=\frac{2}{(4n+1)\pi}\,,\,\,n\in\Bbb N\,,\ldots$$

Answer (score 4):

The function $\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ Does not attain a limit as $x\rightarrow 0$.

Let $f(x)=\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$

$f(x)$ attains a limit $l$ then there exists a $\delta>0$ for every $\epsilon >0$ such that 
$\left|f(x)-l\right|<\epsilon$ such that $0<\left|x-0\right|<\delta$.

Considering it from the right we have $0<x<\delta$ or $\infty<\frac{1}{x}<\frac{1}{\delta}$
. Which means There are infinite number of $\frac{1}{x}$ of the form $2n\pi$. Which means the function is oscillating in the interval and  **limit does not  exist**