# Classifing a singularity.

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

I have the function:

$$f(z)=z \cos\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$$

which has a singularity at $z=0$ and $f(z)\to 0$ as $z\to0$. The theory says that a limit implies that the singularity is removable. But how can you rewrite the function to make it analytic?

EDIT: $f(z)$ does not have a limit as $z$ approaches $0$.

Comment: Are you sure that $f(z) \to 0$ as $z \to 0$? What about for purely imaginary $z$?

Comment: Are you implying that the singularity is removable? It's not true that $\lim \limits_{z\to 0}\left(f(z)\right)=0$.

Comment: @Chappers. I checked again. And you're right. It does not have a limit as I previously thought. And it's definitely not a pole. So it that enough to conclude that it is an essential singularity?

Comment: @GitGud Yes but I was wrong.

Comment: @user302915 A singularity $z_0$ of a function $g$ is essential if $\lim \limits_{z\to z_0}\left(z^ng(z)\right)$is nonexistent for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: This might help:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337980/what-type-of-discontinuity-is-sin1-x

Answer (score 0):

Hint:The function is analytic on the punctured plane $D = \mathbb C-\{0\}$. It has an isolated singularity at $ z = 0$. For $z \neq0$ we have

$$ \cos(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kz^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$

$$ \cos\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$
So
$$ z\cos\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=z \cdot\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$

$$ z\cos\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=z \cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{2!z^2}+\frac{1}{4!z^4}-\frac{1}{6!z^6}+.......\right)$$

$$ z\cos\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=z-\frac{1}{2!z}+\frac{1}{4!z^3}-\frac{1}{6!z^5}+.......$$

Hence $z = 0$ is an **essential singularity** for the function since there are an infnite number of nonzero terms in the Laurent series with negative exponents.