# Type of discontinuity.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Let

$f(x)=\sin\cfrac{1}{x}$

And define f(0)=0.
What is the type of discontinuity in this function?

This is not removable,jump or infinite discontinuity. Then how do i call this discontinuity?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337980/what-type-of-discontinuity-is-sin1-x

Comment: refer to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities

Comment: So we have another  answer already .so let me close this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is defined as “essential” discontinuity since the limit at $x=0$ doesn’t exist.

Comment: Thanks !.......

Comment: @CloudJR You are welcome! Take also a look here http://math.mit.edu/~jspeck/18.01_Fall%202014/Supplementary%20notes/01c.pdf

Comment: it was helpful .Thanks btw

Comment: @CloudJR Well done. Bye

Comment: Is infinite discontinuity a special case of essential discontinuity?

Comment: @dodo Yes, it is a kind of essential discontinuity.